# What error to handle first on a rest resource?

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture, http-status-codes

I'm developing a REST API and when developing the `user` resource I ended up having a doubt. I want the users in my application to view other user profiles without being authenticated. But, obviously, a user needs to be authenticated to edit or delete his profile.

My doubt comes when I access, for example, to this url without been authenticated: `PUT /api/user/1`. Imagine that the user doesn't exists. Which error is checked first, the `404` because the resource does not exist or the `401` because the user is not authenticated? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in querying for that particular user, if the request is a `PUT` and the current user isn't even authenticated. You'd be better off filtering these requests as soon as they hit your endpoint, and return a `401`.